Dropdown menu works on Chrome device mode but not on iOS
I've used the code from this link:
https://dev.to/ljcdev/easy-hamburger-menu-with-js-2do0
I've changed the TS part into this (I'm working with Angular):
  toggleMenu() {
    if (this.menu.classList.contains("showMenu")) {
      this.menu.classList.remove("showMenu");
    } else {
      this.menu.classList.add("showMenu");
    }
  }

And like the headline suggests, it works just fine on my laptop (also on the Chrome's device mode), but when I deploy it and try it from an actual mobile device, it doesn't.
I've tried some solutions from other Stackoverflow threads, like:
css transition not working in mobile chrome,
Problems with Z-index while browsing my page in mobile
But none did the trick... last chance before I delete this cursed dropdown menu code?
Thanks! :)

Could you create a runnable snippet which you've tested definitely shows the problem on mobile, otherwise we have to create something ourselves which may miss the vital bit that is going wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

When you say 'it doean't work' do you mean that the click on the menu isn't seen? What debugging have you tried on mobile? e.g. a simple alert in the toggle function to make sure it's actually being called, or in whatever function is called on the click?

@AHaworth first of all thanks!
it works then it stops after pressing one of the links.
sorry that it's in hebrew. it's for a (political) good cause...
the url is: https://tacheles-7fbc518a6a19.herokuapp.com/
(i'll try to create a runnable snippet)

you can try using the popover api if you arent worried about safari support. this is a native browser api and it handled the complicated parts for you like the indexing. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Popover_API
